# Mulesoft error message propagation through deployed application

Tags: api, error-handling, mule, payload, mulesoft

General explanation of the problem:

how can i get/log inside an application B, the error/exception message produced by an application A (error description and code are generated with a OnErrorPropagate). Application A is a Process API and B is an Experience Api both deployed on cloudHub.

---

More Details:

i have a Process API App. and a Experience API APP. deployed on CloudHub that retrieve client data from a DB.

```
 .../getClient?client_Id=xxx
```

When inside the request the client_id params is not provided the below error message (generated inside an OnErrorPropagate) is shown

```
"message" : "bad request"
```

When a client call the Exp.API APP  `/getClient` without the parameter, the PROCESS API APP (invoked by a flow inside the Exp.API implementation) respond with the above error message.... how can i retrieve this message in my Experience API Application?
If i try lo log the payload response (that should contain the error message) from an Experience API APP log, i always get an empty message.

[image: PROCESS API - Here the error message is generated]

So, is possible to pass an error message generated inside an OnErrorPropagate from an application (PROCESS API APP) to another app (EXPERIENCE API APP)?
All these applications are on cloudhub.  Mulesoft 4

Answer (score 1):

You can capture the the error response payload from the process API which will be present in the error object and set it as response for your experience API using this DW expression

`#[output application/json --- error.exception.errorMessage.typedValue]`

Comment: ...the DE expression give me a null response. I put it inside the OnErrorPropagate of the Process API App. Is it correct?

Comment: From your question, you said your process API gives 400 error, so you need to capture the error thrown by Process API in Experience API. 
In short use this expression in OnErrorPropagate of your Experience API.

Answer (score 0):

You should capture the payload response in the Experience API when you make the HTTP request to the Process API.